# Looking to get a json and csv file from this

Tags: python, json, csv

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20172018/TH020070.HTM").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, "html.parser")

table = soup.table
table = soup.find('table')

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

I am trying to output this to a csv and json. How would i do both(not at the same time). Eventually when i get it properly formatted i would like to dump it straight into postgres. New to python so any help and suggestions would be appreciated. I got help previously with output to csv using pandas but i cant get it to format the way i would like it using pandas although ive been told its much easier..

Comment: JSON out of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to output the `row` variable in each iteration to a JSON / CSV.

For JSON, you can simply dump the list of all `row`s to JSONs. Something like:

```
import json

#Your logic here
rows=[]
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    rows.append(row)
with open("out", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(rows, fp)
```

For CSV, you can use a similar logic as well.

Check out the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: It comes back with a NameError: name 'fp' is not defined

Comment: `fp` is the File Object for the file you want to write to.